# Mocha & Typescript and recursively loading

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

Using this script:

```
"test": "./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --recursive --require ts-node/register ./test/**/*.spec.ts --opts ./test/mocha.opts",
```

I've tried to load some test files inside the tree:

```
.
├── controllers
│   ├── admin
│   │   └── users.spec.ts
│   ├── authentications.spec.ts
```

However, the `users.spec.ts` test file doesn't get loaded but the `authentications.spec.ts` does.

My mocha.opts file looks like just:

```
--timeout 5000
```

I've also tried to remove the `--recursive` flag and just have a glob but it doesn't work.

I can't work out whether the problem is with `ts-node` or with `mocha`?

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem. Using `./test/**/**/*.spec.ts` (two `**` paths) allows mocha to find and run the lower-level test (`users.spec.ts` in your case), but at the cost that it no longer finds the higher-level tests.

Comment: `./test/**/*.spec.ts --opts`  will resolve the folder which consits of .spec.ts      `./test/**/*.spec.ts --opts` will resolve the file inside the `test/ --> folder`

Comment: Try wrap path in single quote `'./test/**/**/*.spec.ts'` source

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you also asked this question [here](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/3115), and got a good answer: quote the glob argument, so that it's expanded (recursively) by mocha, rather than by the shell (non-recursively):

```
"test": "mocha --require ts-node/register 'test/**/*.spec.ts' --opts ./test/mocha.opts"
```

Answer (score 3):

It certainly seems that there is a bug here, whether in mocha's handling of `--recursive` or some interaction with `ts-node` I don't know.

You can work around this by telling mocha to specifically look for more deeply nested folders by using a command like:

```
mocha --recursive --require ts-node/register ./test/**/*.spec.ts ./test/**/**/*.spec.ts --opts ./test/mocha.opts
```

eg., tell it to specifically look in both the child (`/**/`) and grandchild (`/**/**/`) directories.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was actually that I had an `only` in the tests